# Are there libraries for custom re-usable views?

Tags: android

Are there libraries for android custom views? Re-usable components?

I did not found much on that topic. Just see everybody creates his own custom components, drawables and so on. Especially things like a homescreen-like viewswitcher and things like that, which reoccur often would be nice to have in a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check:

1. [What Android 3rd-party libraries are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there)
2. [Android: how can i improve the look of an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296767/android-how-can-i-improve-the-look-of-an-app)

Answer (score 2):

You can put them into an [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects). [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) how to use them in Eclipse.

Comment: thanks for your input. But maybe i have to clarify. I don't want to write a library myself. I want to find and use such libraries