# Where i can check the main standards for making android user interfaces?

Tags: android, user-interface

i need a link where i can read and understand the main standards to follow where making android user interfaces

i can't find it on google

thanks

Comment: You can also have a look at Google I/O 2010 - Android UI design patterns: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the developer guide?

You can find it over here: [Google Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Comment: yes i check it and i dind't find any info about user interface standards to follow. I only found code examples and coding guide...

Comment: More specifically for user interfaces : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: no these info is about how to code it, i am checking info about how to make usable interfaces

Comment: You could take a look at [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AndroidDev/android-ui-design-tips). There are some tips and tricks to design an intuitive ui.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [Android UI guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html)?

Comment: no these info is about how to code it, i am checking info about how to make usable interfaces

Comment: Where did you see stuff about coding in the link? The guidelines describe how the application should look and function, not how to code them. Android users expect Android applications to follow the platform conventions. If you follow these well, then your application will be usable for Android users. If you are looking for general design guidelines, then you should buy any generic design textbook and read.

Answer (score 1):

You should Google for User Interface Guidelines or smth.. 
Check this out

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

Comment: no these info is about how to code it, i am checking info about how to make usable interfaces

Comment: Then u need a research paper!! check out usability guidelines for apple and windows !!

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that a lot (but obviously not all by any means) of Apple's [iOS human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) may be transferable to Android HI design. Might be worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

Probably related and useful: [How can I improve the look and feel of an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296767/android-how-can-i-improve-the-look-of-an-app/)

Lots of useful links listed there.