# JGoodies for Android?

Tags: java, android, jgoodies

I looking for an UI plugin library for Android like what JGoodies is to Swing.

It should be configurable with or without the library existing (meaning, if the library exists, it renders the UI component specific to library, otherwise use the default android ui)

regards,
kiwi

Answer (score 1):

Although there is none that I know like JGoodies, I think the following two links will be of help for you:

- [Using Themes in Android Applications](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)
- [Android: how can i improve the look of an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5296767/851432)

Answer (score 1):

I think responses so far are missing the point of JGoodies (and where I am presuming the question isn't about look-and-feel). It's predominantly not a look-and-feel library, it's a mechanism for automatically firing relevant events throughout a GUI, based on other changes on the same screen.