# what are the android UI Designing tools

Tags: android

Last 6 months I am working in android mobile application development. My question is, any body use any special tool for android UI design except DroiDrow. Which one is mostly using for UI design?

Comment: Have you tried editing the layout files directly?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lots of designing tools for android [here](http://webdesignledger.com/tools/useful-tools-and-kits-for-android-developers)

Thanks,

Comment: thank u.which one is best designing tool for android? and plz explain me why?

Comment: Sry Vinay, I didn't get a chance to use any, other than Droiddraw.

Answer (score 2):

For prototyping of user interfaces i'm using [Pencil Project](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) It has plugin with [android templates](http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/downloads/detail?name=Android-4.0-Stencils.zip) which can be downloaded from official site. Also, it is exists as plugin for firefox or as standalone desktop application and crossplatform, free and under opensource license

Answer (score 1):

[this question may be useful for u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296767/android-how-can-i-improve-the-look-of-an-app)

[this tutorial use to create themes for android](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)

[Android UI patterns](http://sixrevisions.com/user-interface/mobile-ui-design-patterns-inspiration/)

[design tutorial](http://www.androiduipatterns.com)